# Flutter RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 2

Tags: flutter, api, dart, model

I can't fetch the initial default address 0 in the next username. It is often a problem when a large number of addresses are found in the list of addresses.

after some fixes type 'sting' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'

The data in the address will be included in the same set of items.

Please help me I am practicing fetch api

This is Code

```
     List<Items> _list = [];
    List<Items> _search = [];
    var loading = false;
    Future fetchMos() async {
   setState(() {
  loading = true;
});
_list.clear();
var client = http.Client();
String mosUrl =
    '';

var url = Uri.parse(mosUrl);
var headers = {
  'Client-Token': '',
};
var response = await client.get(url, headers: headers);
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  var data = jsonDecode((utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes)))['items'];
  setState(() {
    for (var index in data) {
      _list.add(Items.fromJson(index));
      loading = false;
    }
  });
}
}

  @override
     void initState() {
 // TODO: implement initState
 super.initState();
 fetchMos();
 }

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    elevation: 0.0,
  ),
  body: ListView.builder(
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      if (_list.length > 0) {
        return _listItem(index);
      } else {
        return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      }
    },
    itemCount: _list.length,
  ),
);
```

}

```
          _listItem(index) {
                return Card(
              elevation: 3,
            child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
                      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5),
            child: Text(
              "${_list[index].name}  ${_list[index].custnum}",
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontSize: 18,
                  fontFamily: "supermarket"),
            ),
          ),
          TextButton(
            child: const Text(
              'แก้ไข',
              style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "supermarket", fontSize: 14),
            ),
            onPressed: () {/* ... */},
          ),
        ],
      ),
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Text(
              'bill To / Ship To : ${_list[index].address![index].shipto.toString()}',
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontSize: 16,
                  fontFamily: "supermarket"),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            Text(
              "ที่อยู่ : ${_list[index].address![index].addr1.toString()}",
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontSize: 16,
                  fontFamily: "supermarket"),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

}
}

This is json

```
 {
 "items": [
   {
    "custnum": "",
    "name": "",
    "address": [
        {
            "shipto": 0,
            "addr1": "",
            "thanon": "",
            "tambon": "",
            "amphur": "",
            "prov_code": "",
            "province": "",
            "zipcode": "",
            "country": "",
            "contact": "",
            "postcode": ""
        },
        {
           "shipto": 1,
            "addr1": "",
            "thanon": "",
            "tambon": "",
            "amphur": "",
            "prov_code": "",
            "province": "",
            "zipcode": "",
            "country": "",
            "contact": "",
            "postcode": ""
        },
        {
            "shipto": 2,
            "addr1": "",
            "thanon": "",
            "tambon": "",
            "amphur": "",
            "prov_code": "",
            "province": "",
            "zipcode": "",
            "country": "",
            "contact": "",
            "postcode": ""
        },
        {
            "shipto": 3,
            "addr1": "",
            "thanon": "",
            "tambon": "",
            "amphur": "",
            "prov_code": "",
            "province": "",
            "zipcode": "",
            "country": "",
            "contact": "",
            "postcode": ""
        }
    ]
},
    {
    "custnum": "",
    "name": "",
    "address": [
        {
            "shipto": 0,
            "addr1": "",
            "thanon": "",
            "tambon": "",
            "amphur": "",
            "prov_code": "",
            "province": "",
            "zipcode": "",
            "country": "",
            "contact": "",
            "postcode": ""
        },
        {
           "shipto": 1,
            "addr1": "",
            "thanon": "",
            "tambon": "",
            "amphur": "",
            "prov_code": "",
            "province": "",
            "zipcode": "",
            "country": "",
            "contact": "",
            "postcode": ""
        },
        {
            "shipto": 2,
            "addr1": "",
            "thanon": "",
            "tambon": "",
            "amphur": "",
            "prov_code": "",
            "province": "",
            "zipcode": "",
            "country": "",
            "contact": "",
            "postcode": ""
        },
        {
            "shipto": 3,
            "addr1": "",
            "thanon": "",
            "tambon": "",
            "amphur": "",
            "prov_code": "",
            "province": "",
            "zipcode": "",
            "country": "",
            "contact": "",
            "postcode": ""
        }
  ],
```

Answer (score 0):

```
      Text(
        'bill To / Ship To : ${_list[index].address![index].shipto.toString()}',
        style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16, fontFamily: "supermarket"),
      ),
```

As per the above code, you using the same **index** for **_list** and **address** array. so maybe that will create this issue.

```
${_list[index].address![index].shipto.toString()}
```

I don't think this is right bcz when your **index is 10** then

```
_list[10].address![10].shipto.toString()
```

if the **address** has not **10 elements** then it will throw that exception.

and the same things to this code

```
"ที่อยู่ : ${_list[index].address![index].addr1.toString()}"
```